# Elasticsearch: Getting offsets of a matching keyword

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm new to Elasticsearch. I have created an index named "files". Then I have added a document contains fields name,content under the type "text" and id 1.like below.

```html
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/files/text/1?pretty' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
    "name" : "Readme",
    "content" : "Hi this is a sample document.I created this document to explore the features of elasticsearch"
}'
```

I want to search in the 'content' field of this document for a keyword [for eg.'this'] and get its offsets. Is it possible ?. Actually my requirement is to get the offsets of a keyword in 'n' documents in an index

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: I tried this .. curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/files/_search?pretty' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
    "query" : {
        "match": { "content": "this" }
    }}'

Comment: I tried 'highlight' option also. but it only highlight the occurrences, I need offsets